# mailersend smtp relay setup with c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

i am trying to send an email with c# using the mailersend smtp service

i have set the SFP, DKIM, and return path dns records and everything is verified

also i have enabled the smtp service on the dashboard

but i get an error on sending :

> Recipient domain must match senders domain

here my code:

```
var @from = "labresult@netlab.i-software.net"; //this match the registred domain, note that is a subdomain ad not a tld
var to = "someemailadress";
var subject = "test lab";
var body = "it works !!!!";

var username = "myusername"; // get from Mailtrap
var password = "mypass"; // get from Mailtrap

var host = "smtp.mailersend.net";
var port = 587;

var client = new SmtpClient(host, port)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
    EnableSsl = true
};

client.Send(@from, to, subject, body);
```

any idea on how to fix it
[image: DNS records]

Comment: Are you using a trial account?

Comment: the free plan .

Comment: That might be why. Providers like this usually have this limitation for free plans. Check their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should ask to [be approved](https://www.mailersend.com/help/getting-started#account-verification) so your domain isn't limited. While pending approval, your domain can only send to recipients from the same domain, so mailersend.com can only send to jane@mailersend.com.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).